# Solving equality of $3\times3$ determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

In Basic Mathematics, Lang, exercise of section 17.5...
[image]
Gives this answer...
[image]

My own calculations gave...

$(x_2-x_1)(x_3^2-x_1^2)-(x_3-x_1)(x_2^2-x_1^2)$

Is it correct?

Comment: It is correct, but the factorisation is not finished.

Comment: $x_3^2-x_1^2=(x_3-x_1)(x_3+x_1)$ and $(x_2^2-x_1^2)=(x_2-x_1)(x_2+x_1).$ So your expression is $(x_2-x_1)(x_3-x_1)\left[(x_3+x_1)-(x_2+x_1)\right]=(x_2-x_1)(x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2).$

Comment: Yes, it is. From your result, factor out $(x_2-x_1)(x_3-x_1)$ and you'll obtain what gives  the book

Comment: @Thomas Andrews, you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Thank you everyone. @ThomasAndrews, how did you come up with this equality? $x_3^2-x_1^2=(x_3-x_1)(x_3+x_1)$

Comment: @F. Zer, $(x_3-x_1)(x_3+x_1)=(x_3-x_1)x_3+(x_3-x_1)x_1=x_3^2-x_1x_3+x_3x_1-x_1^2=x_3^2-x_1^2$

Comment: where I used distributive law in first and second steps, and commutative and cancellation laws in the next step.

Comment: Thank you, @Martund. $x_3^2$, where does it come from? I can’t see it. How do you go from your second equality to the third?

Comment: Got it, @Martund.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would calculate in a slightly different way, in order to obtain directly a formula easier to memorise:
\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix}
1&x_1&x_1^2 \\
1&x_2&x_2^2 \\
1&x_3&x_3^2 \\
\end{vmatrix}
&= 
\begin{vmatrix}
0&x_1-x_2&x_1^2-x_2^2 \\
0&x_2-x_3&x_2^2-x_3^2 \\
1&x_3&x_3^2 \\
\end{vmatrix}
=(x_1-x_2)(x_2-x_3)
\begin{vmatrix}
0&1&x_1+x_2 \\
0&1&x_2+x_3 \\
1&x_3&x_3^2 \\
\end{vmatrix} \\
&=(x_1-x_2)(x_2-x_3)\bigl((x_2+x_3)-(x_1+x_2)\bigl) \\
&=\color{red}{(x_1-x_2)(x_2-x_3)(x_3-x_1)}.
\end{align}

Comment: Could you explain how do you go from the second term to the third in your chain of equalities ?

Comment: Yes: the determinant is linear w.r.t. each row (and each column), so I factored out the common factor in row 2 and in row 3.

Comment: What does “the determinant is linear” mean?

Comment: It is a function of the rows, say $f(r_1, r_2,r_3)$ which satisfies the following properties: $$f(\lambda r_1+\mu r'_1, r_2,r_3)=\lambda f(r_1, r_2,r_3)+\mu f(r'_1, r_2,r_3)$$ and similarly for the second and third rows. Is it clear?

Comment: Thank you, @Bernard. Not entirely clear as I am beginning with linear algebra. Could you explain please how other answers come up with this equality ? I can't see it. $$(x_3-x_1)x_3+(x_3-x_1)x_1=x_3^2-x_1x_3+x_3x_1-x_1^2$$ Where does $x_3^2$ come from?

Comment: You mean the equality in my comment, which expresses multilinearity? It is used in Serge Lang's book (3rd equality), for me it is used in the second equality. For you 2nd question, do you mean the $x_3^2$ is your comment's display equation? It comes from from the expansion of by distributivity: $(x_3-x_1)x_3=x_3\cdot x_3-x_1\cdot x_3=x_3^2-x_1x_3$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because $$(x_2-x_1)(x_3-x_1)(x_3+x_1)-(x_3-x_1)(x_2-x_1)(x_2+x_1)=(x_2-x_1)(x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2).$$

Another method, which requires basically no calculation: the determinant is a homogeneous cubic in the $x_i$, both fully antisymmetric and invariant under a cyclic permutation of them. It must therefore be proportional to $(x_2-x_1)(x_3-x_2)(x_3-x_1)$, and the proportionality constant is the $x_1^2x_3$ coefficient, which is $\epsilon_{231}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answer is  correcr. $$(x_2-x_1)(x_3^2-x_1^2)-(x_3-x_1)(x_2^2-x_1^2)=$$

$$ (x_2-x_1)(x_3-x_1)(x_3+x_1)-(x_3-x_1)(x_2-x_1)(x_2+x_1)$$

Facotor the common terms and simplify to get their answer.